# RadioGroup Visibility Issue at Runtime

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-activity, android-radiogroup

I have written a small logic around Visibility of RadioGroup, but it fails when I tried it:

```
if ("some condition") {
     showAlert("Some Message");
} else if ("some condition") {
     showAlert("Some Message");
} else if(radioGroup.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

     if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please make a selection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return;
     }

 } else {

   saveData();
   finish();

}
```

Also tried THIS:

```
 if ("some condition") {
     showAlert("Some Message");
 } else if ("some condition") {
     showAlert("Some Message");   
 } else {

     if(radioGroup.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

     if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please make a selection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return;
     }

     else {

          saveData();
          finish();
      }

    }

    else {

       saveData();
       finish();
   }    

}
```

What I have tried above,

I am just trying to show the Toast "Please make a selection" if Radio Group is `Visible` and none of the radio button is selected as you can in my above code, but I am getting this message "Please make a selection" even **RadioGroup** is `not visible` in an Activity.

Where I have made the mistake ? Why I am getting "Please make a selection" message even RadioGroup is not visible in an Activity ?

Comment: check radiogroup.isShown() instead of getVisiblit()

Answer (score 0):

Try This, it might help

```
    if(radioGroup.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please make a selection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
    } else {
    saveData();
    finish();
    }
} else { 
    if ("some condition 1") {showAlert("Some Message 1");}
 else {showAlert("Some Message 2");}
}
```

Good Luck

Comment: I have to all these conditions along RadioGroup visibility's condition

Comment: could you explain more, do you need other conditions with the visibility status ?